# ORACLE 11g: Distinct row without losing differences (pivot?)

Tags: oracle, pivot, distinct

I have to group row with a specific name without lost differences in specific columns.

Take a query like this thats search medical procedure and every structure where you can perform them:

Select NAME, .... from TABLE (various join) WHERE STRUCTURE_CODE IN ('0123456','0999912')

```
| NAME            | STRUCTURE_CODE   | AGE_LIMIT | BIRTHPLACE_LIMIT |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
|RX ABS           | 0123456          | NULL      | NULL             |
|RX ABS           | 0999912          | 50        | NULL             |
|HEAD RESONANCE   | 0999912          | NULL      | NULL             |
|ABS RESONANCE    | 0123456          | 30        | NULL             |
|ABS RESONANCE    | 0999912          | NULL      | ROME             |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

(NOTE: head resonance is only performed by structure 0999912)

Due to join and result columns, the query duplicate row with same name because some other columns has different values (like AGE_LIMIT etc...).

I have to show on web one row for every distinct NAME and then specify what are the limits every structure has (if there is any). I can accepts a CONCAT of strings like this:

```
| NAME            | AGE_LIMIT                    | BIRTHPLACE_LIMIT                      |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|RX ABS           | 0123456.NULL;0999912.50      | 0123456.NULL;0999912.NULL             |
|HEAD RESONANCE   | 0999912.NULL;                | 0999912.NULL;                         |
|ABS RESONANCE    | 0123456.30;0999912.NULL      | 0123456.NULL;0999912.ROME             |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Java will transalte, before rendering the web page, the concatenated string to translate them in a more readable way.

Is this possible or do you thinks there is another elegant solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the letters N, U, L, L to be included in the output strings to mark "null" - or did you write NULL to mean no text at all? In either case, why is there nothing after the ; in the HEAD RESONANCE row? If you want the word NULL to appear, it should appear after the ;  and even if you just want NULL to actually mean "no text at all" shouldn't you at least have a period (.) there, to mark the separator between NULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    NAME,
    LISTAGG(STRUCTURE_CODE||'.'||AGE_LIMIT , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY STRUCTURE_CODE) AS AGE_LIMIT ,
    LISTAGG(STRUCTURE_CODE||'.'||BIRTHPLACE_LIMIT , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY STRUCTURE_CODE) AS BIRTHPLACE_LIMIT                        
FROM "TABLE" GROUP BY NAME
```

Comment: You might want to change `STRUCTURE_CODE||'.'||AGE_LIMIT` to `STRUCTURE_CODE||'.'||COALESCE(AGE_LIMIT,'NULL')` as the OP seems to want to append `NULL` as a string (and the same for `BIRTHPLACE_LIMIT`).

Comment: LISTAGG(STRUCTURE_CODE||'.'||AGE_LIMIT , ',') ->>LISTAGG(STRUCTURE_CODE||'.'||NVL(AGE_LIMIT,NULL) , ',')

Comment: The query with the COALESCE options is working fine. I only add a TO_CHAR function to AGE_LIMIT because they are NUMBER type and COALESCE want every arguments of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is `pivot xml`. This is possibly easier to read in further processing:

```
with data(name,
structure_code,
age_limit,
birthplace_limit) as
 (select 'RX ABS', 0123456, NULL, NULL
    from dual
  union all
  select 'RX ABS', 0999912, 50, NULL
    from dual
  union all
  select 'HEAD RESONANCE', 0999912, NULL, NULL
    from dual
  union all
  select 'ABS RESONANCE', 0123456, 30, NULL
    from dual
  union all
  select 'ABS RESONANCE', 0999912, NULL, 'ROME'
    from dual)
select *
  from data
pivot xml (max(age_limit) as age_limit, max(birthplace_limit) as birthplace_limit for structure_code in(any))
 order by name;
```

Result:

```
NAME            STRUCTURE_CODE_XML
ABS RESONANCE   <XMLTYPE>
HEAD RESONANCE  <XMLTYPE>
RX ABS          <XMLTYPE>
```

Second column contains the data in xml format:

```
<PivotSet><item><column name = "STRUCTURE_CODE">123456</column><column name = "AGE_LIMIT">30</column><column name = "BIRTHPLACE_LIMIT"></column></item><item><column name = "STRUCTURE_CODE">999912</column><column name = "AGE_LIMIT"></column><column name = "BIRTHPLACE_LIMIT">ROME</column></item></PivotSet>
```